# "Wrong Entity ID" when Installing Extension (Database Litter?)

Tags: magento2, database, extensions

I've run into a dead end trying to install an extension and am hoping for some guidance. The extension is Blackbird_ContentManager -- great extension and support overall, but I can't figure out what's going on here.

At first, I received

```
Blackbird_ContentManager data: current version - none, required version - 2.2.12
```

So when I run setup:upgrade, it got to Installing Data and then:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or 
update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`db_5798qz73hik`.`eav_entity_attribute`, CONSTRAINT 
`EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID` FOREIGN 
KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON D), 
query was: INSERT INTO `eav_entity_attribute` (`entity_type_id`, 
`attribute_set_id`, `attribute_group_id`, `attribute_id`, `sort_order`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Sometimes it'll make it it to the "Installing Data" phase of setup, but then I'll receive "Wrong entity ID" error. This is after deleting all relevant eav_* and blackbird_* tables/rows, as well as the entry in setup_module.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm unsure what to do that I haven't already done and am getting increasingly nervous. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Delete all the data related to this extension and remove the entry from setup module table and then run setup upgrade.

Comment: Hey @SukumarGorai -- I've actually already tried that, edited question to reflect that. Thank you.

Comment: can you try in your extension first disable the foreign key check and after execution of query enable foreign key check.

Comment: Tried that earlier, wasn't successful. My issue has been resolved, though, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this by resetting auto-increments on all relevant tables. A product transfer integration added a bunch of attribute sets/attributes, which somehow threw the increments out of wack.